# Is $\{x\in\mathbb R:\cos(x)=p/q\text{ where }p,q\in\mathbb N\}$ countable?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know if the following set is countable or uncountable.

\begin{equation*}
\left\{x\in\mathbb R: \cos (x)=\frac{p}{q} \text{ where } p,q \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
\end{equation*}
 I think it is not countable. Because I could not find a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and the above set. Am I correct?

Comment: No, that's not right. Failing to find a bijection may be (rather weak) evidence against countability, a proof would have to come from some kind of diagonalisation argument, or a surjection onto a known uncountable set (like $\Bbb{R}$).

Comment: Instead, recall that countable unions of countable sets are countable. This might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more formal:

Let. $S :=$

{$(p/q)| 0 \le p/q \le 1, q\not =0, p,q \in \mathbb{N}$};

$S \subset \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Consider:

$\arccos :  [-1,1] \rightarrow [kπ,(k+1)π]$,  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, is a bijection:

$\arccos (p/q) =x_{p,q}(k)$

$A_k:=${$x_{p,q}(k)|(p/q) \in [-1,1]$} is countable.

$\bigcup_{k}A_k$ is countable.

Answer (score 4):

For each $p$ and $q$, the set $S_{p,q}=\{x:\cos\, x=\frac p q\}$ is at most countable. The given set is $\cup_{p,q \in \mathbb N} S_{p,q}$ and hence it is countable.

Added after seeing a downvote: if you draw the graph of the cosine function you can see that it meets any horizontal line at at a countably infinite number of points or never. This makes $S_{p,q}$ as most countable for any $p$ and $q$.

Comment: +1. As usual a down-voter declined to say why.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you for you comment and for your vote. If these people make  a comment it will help us to improve the way we  answer questions and everyone is benefited.

Comment: +1. Nice and simple argument

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is countable. Observe that the function $\cos$ gives a bijection from the intersection of your set with $[0,2\pi)$ to $\mathbb Q$. By applying this argument to other periods of $\cos$ you obtain a representation of your set as a countable union of countable sets, and hence it is countable.